# How to return a value in a method which is the same value returned in a try?

Tags: c#

I am actually programming in C# and I have a problem, I don't know if the method is returning what I want.
In fact i am using a try/catch fonction and I am returning a value (cellValue1) in it and at the end of my method, i am returning" "" ; ".

What does the method return at the end ? I want to return the same value as in the try fonction ?

Here is my code :

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace excel
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void ReadExcel()
        {
           Var log = ConstLog.AreaLog.item1;
           log+= "\n"
           log+= "[REGION]-[read excel] : method read excel started" +"\n"; 
foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Lionel84100\Desktop\Excel"))
{
         string filepath = @"C:\Users\Lionel84100\Desktop\Excel\fezfFzfe.xlsx";
            try
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = null;
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                if (filepath.IndexOf(".xlsx") > 0)
                {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                }
                else if (filepath.IndexOf(".xls") > 0)
                {
                    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                }

                ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("Formatage_IM");
                if (sheet != null)
                {
                    int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum;


                    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)

                    {
                        IRow curRow = sheet.GetRow(i);

                        string cellValue1 = curRow.GetCell(1).StringCellValue;
                        
                        return cellValue1;
                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
}
            
          return log;

        }
```

I have replaced string in the starting of the method by a void but there is an error saying that i can't return a value since the method in a void .

Comment: A method that isn't `void` always has to return something. If the code in `try` fails, you won't be returning anything. If `rowCount == 0`, you won't return anything in the `try` either. You need `return "";` (or something) for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

the method returns the value of the first cell in the excel file if the file exists, if no, it returns empty string

Answer (score 0):

A method that does not return `void` must always return a value, *except when it returns with an exception*.

```cs
public string Foo(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        return "Zero";
    }
    // If you remove/comment the following line, the function will not compile.
    return "Not Zero";
}
```

The same applies when there are try/catch handlers in a function:

```cs
public string Foo(int i)
{
    try
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            return "Zero";
        }
        // If you remove/comment the following line, the function will not compile.
        return "Not Zero";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // If you remove the following line, the function will also not compile, 
        // because if you handle an exception in a function, it needs to return a value as well (or rethrow the exception)
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

On the other hand (as in your example) a function returning `void` *must not* return a value. That means that either there must be no argument after a `return` statement or no return statement at all.

So for your function, you need to change the return type from `void` to `string` and make sure you return a value in the other cases as well (or throw an exception if you don't find the value/cell).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have one last question, I have put "throw" in the catch and I am returning something else a the end of the method, it is the value log which will be helpful for me for the log messages. But I still want to return cell value1 for my other method. Is it okay ? I have edited the code in my question.

Comment: Yes, that basically works. `log` will be returned when neither the cell is found nor an exception happens (i.e when there are no matching files). However, you will not be able to distinguish the cases. It would probably be better to add an out parameter for the error, so that you have separate return entities for the content and the error.